# extracting paragraphs from text with perl

Tags: perl

I want to extract the paragraphs from a text variable that retrieved from the DB.

for extracting the pargaphs from file handler i use the below code :

```
local $/ = undef;
@paragarphs =<STDIN>
```

what is the best option to extract paragraphs from a text variable using perl and if there are module on cpan that do this type of task ?

Comment: You've changed your code to reflect my answer. That will be confusing for others who read this post. Please rollback.

Comment: Yes I changed it but i meant there local $/=""

Comment: Set $/ to whatever you call paragraph delimiter

Comment: $ perl -ane 'BEGIN { $/="";} { chomp; push @ paras, $_; } END { push @ paras, ""; print join "\n\n", @ paras; }' INFILE

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're almost there. Setting `$/` to `undef` will slurp in the entire text in one go.

What you want is `local $/ = "";` to enable paragraph mode, as per [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) (emphasis my own):

> **$/**
>
> The input record separator, newline by default. This influences Perl's
>   idea of what a "line" is. Works like awk's RS variable, including
>   treating empty lines as a terminator if set to the null string (an
>   empty line cannot contain any spaces or tabs). You may set it to a
>   multi-character string to match a multi-character terminator, or to
>   undef to read through the end of file. Setting it to "\n\n" means
>   something slightly different than setting to "" , if the file contains
>   consecutive empty lines. **Setting to "" will treat two or more
>   consecutive empty lines as a single empty line.** Setting to "\n\n"
>   will blindly assume that the next input character belongs to the next
>   paragraph, even if it's a newline.

---

Of course, it is possible to get a filehandle to read from a string instead of a file:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $text = <<TEXT;
This is a paragraph.

Here's another one that 
spans over multiple lines.

Last paragraph
TEXT

local $/ = "";
open my $fh, '<', \$text;

while ( <$fh> ) {

    print "New Paragraph: $_";
}

close $fh;
```

**Output**

```
New Paragraph: This is a paragraph.

New Paragraph: Here's another one that
spans over multiple lines.

New Paragraph: Last paragraph
```

Comment: Ok how i extract the paragraphs from this variable $text for example? also you are right but i want to extract the paragaphs from text and not file handle

Comment: @smith In that case, write an regex, and use `split`. This will have a similar effect: `my @paragraphs = split /\n\n+/, $text` for a strict setting, IRL I tend to use the `/\s*?\n\s*\n/` regex to treat lines containing only whitespaces as empty lines.

Comment: @smith : I've added an example that shows how to open a filehandle to a string... hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

You already have the answer for a script (`local $/ = "";`), but it may be worth noting that there is a shortcut for one-liners: the `-00` option.

```
perl -00 -ne '$count++; END {print "Counted $count paragraphs\n"}' somefile.txt
```

From `man perlrun` :

> -0[octal/hexadecimal]
>
> specifies the input record separator ($/) [...]
>
> The special value 00 will cause Perl to slurp files in paragraph
>   mode.

Answer (score -3):

If the text is in a variable, for example:

```
$text = "Here is a paragraph.\nHere is another paragraph.";
```

or:

```
$text = 'Paragraph 1
Paragraph2';
```

You can simply get the paragraphs by splitting the text with "\n".

```
@paragraphs = split("\n",$text);
```

If your paragraphs are separated by double newlines or a combination of \n and \r (like in Windows) you can change the split command accordingly.

Comment: The OP's original code will already behaves like this (when not setting `$/`), and further it doesn't need to read the entire file into memory to do it.

Comment: This is wrong, because in the context of programming and plain text files, a paragraph is not a line of text. Paragraphs are groups of 1 or more lines of text separated by an empty line.