# Cannot successfully extract paragraphs using perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to use PERL to extract paragraphs from a text. However, the code does not generate the results I expect. I benefit a lot from the answers by Zaid from this post [extracting paragraphs from text with perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561822/extracting-paragraphs-from-text-with-perl). Here are the codes I wrote:

#

```
my $string = <<'TEXT';
     Assembly and Manufacturing

     The Company's assembly and manufacturing operations include PCB assembly
and the manufacture of subsystems and complete products. Its PCB assembly
activities primarily consist of the placement and attachment of electronic and
mechanical components on printed circuit boards using both SMT and traditional
pin-through-hole ("PTH") technology. The Company also assembles subsystems and
systems incorporating PCBs and complex electromechanical components, and,
increasingly, manufactures and packages final products for shipment directly to
the customer or its distribution channels. The Company employs just-in-time,
ship-to-stock and ship-to-line programs, continuous flow manufacturing, demand
flow processes and statistical process control. The Company has expanded the
number of production lines for finished product assembly, burn-in and test to
meet growing demand and increased customer requirements. In addition, the
Company has invested in FICO, a producer of injection molded plastic for Asia
electronics companies with facilities in Shenzhen, China.

     As OEMs seek to provide greater functionality in smaller products, they
increasingly require advanced manufacturing technologies and processes. Most of
the Company's PCB assembly involves the use of SMT, which is the leading
electronics assembly technique for more sophisticated products. SMT is a
computer-automated process which permits attachment of components directly on
both sides of a PCB. As a result, it allows higher integration of electronic
components, offering smaller size, lower cost and higher reliability than
traditional manufacturing processes. By allowing increasingly complex circuits
to be packaged with the components placed in closer proximity to each other, SMT
greatly enhances circuit processing speed, and therefore board and system
performance. The Company also provides traditional PTH electronics assembly
using PCBs and leaded components for lower cost products.;
TEXT

local $/ = "";
open my ($str_fh), '<', \$string;
while ( <$str_fh> ) {
     print "New Paragraph: $_\n","*" x 40, "\n" ;   
}
close $str_fh;
```

#

The text is from annual report of this company https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/32272/0000950147-97-000151.txt.

I expect the code returns the paragraphs, however, I got the whole text back. 
Would anyone help me with this issue? I am quite confused with these errors.

Thanks so much!!!

Best Regards

Comment: Change $/ to  "\n\n"? Two paragraph is separate by a blank line. Read the manual of `$/`.

Comment: Search for INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR in perldoc perlvar http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html

Comment: The text you quoted does not come from the link you provided.  Could you provide the _actual_ link?

Comment: @ngn999 Thanks for your reply! I have changed to "\n\n" and however, still it does not work well...It still returns the whole text..

Comment: @ngn999 Can I ask one more question: is it possible to still get paragraphs separately even if the current blank lines do not count as paragraph separator? Thank you!

Comment: @xxfelixxx Thanks for your reply! I will check the INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR and check whether it will improve the answer. The text I posted here is part of the link I posted. Can I ask one more question: is it possible to still get paragraphs separately even if the current blank lines do not count as paragraph separator? Thank you!

Comment: first, delete trailing white space?

Comment: Your code works. What's the problem you're having?

Comment: @Sobrique I have tried that if I copy and paste the code I post and run again, It prints each paragraph separately. However, when I directly analyse the whole file (the link I post), for this part it returns the whole text back (instead of printing each paragraph). I am sure why this happens, maybe copy and paste changes the paragraph separator? Thanks much!

Answer (score 2):

When I run the code you posted here, it works fine.  It prints each paragraph separately.

Most likely, the lines between paragraphs are not completely blank.  If there are spaces on the "blank" lines, then they don't count as paragraph separators.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The text is a part of the company's annual report (the link I posted). I think It is quite possible the "blank" lines have spaces so that I cannot get the paragraphs separately, maybe different companies have different styles in writing these files. Can I ask one more question: is it possible to still get paragraphs separately even if the "blank" have spaces? Thank you!

Comment: Not using `$/`. You'll have to iterate and use regular expressions instead.

Comment: @Sobrique Thanks for the reply! I will try to do that. But still I have no idea what paragraph separators the text uses and is there any way I can know that? Thanks! Best Regards.

Comment: The text file you linked to works fine with the code you posted (just changing it to open the downloaded file instead of a string).  If you're still having problems, post more details.

Comment: There are ways, but it's a bit too hard to answer in the comments.